# php 7.3 - Class constants as default param values crashing

Tags: php, default-value

I have some code that has been working for a long time, but is now producing perplexing errors. I have to assume this was caused by my moving to php 7.3, but I can't find any references that explain what is happening.

I have a method in a class that looks something like:

```
class Foo {

    function bar($param = OtherClass::MY_CONSTANT) {
        logger(__METHOD__);
        logger(OtherClass::MY_CONSTANT);
        logger($param);
        logger('ready to do stuff');

        // does stuff
    }
}
```

Where OtherClass::MY_CONSTANT = 1.

When I call that method from another class:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar();
```

the output is something like:

```
DEBUG - Foo::bar
DEBUG - 1
```

and then php execution stops abruptly, not even calling my registered shutdown function. I am able to use the class constant directly in the body of the method, but I am not able to use the parameter set to the class constant's value by default.

If I change the method to

```
function bar($param = 1) {
```

everything works fine.

Also, if I pass the constant when I call the method it works:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar(OtherClass::MY_CONSTANT);
```

I get the happy

```
DEBUG - Foo::bar
DEBUG - 1
DEBUG - 1
DEBUG - ready to do stuff
```

and execution continues normally.

Something about using a class constant as a default is making the variable poisonous, even though I can use the class constant in the method without any trouble.

I tried to create a simple one-file example to recreate this problem, but it worked just fine. Aargh.

Has something changed in php 7.3 that would cause this behavior? I just upgraded to 7.3.1 but the problem persisted. Is there a better practice I should be using?

EDIT TO ADD:

After a few hours trying to make a simple case to reproduce this, I have to move on. Relevant factors include:

- running in php-fpm
- code running after closing the connection to the browser.
- even constants in the same class (`self::MY_CONSTANT`) create poison variables

My solution was to roll back to php 7.2.14, which is working properly. I can only assume this in a bug in php 7.3.

Comment: What version did you move from?

Comment: I first saw the problem with 7.3.0, updating to 7.3.1 had no effect. Before that I was using 7.2, and I did not notice the problem at that time.

Comment: What's the PHP error?

Comment: No error at all. Complete and catastrophic stop of processing.

Comment: You should turn up `error_reporting` and make sure `display_errors` is on.

Comment: Used `spl_autoload_register()` or `include_once`? Constant is public?

Comment: no autoloader; it uses `include_once`. `error_reporting` is `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Comment: WFM https://3v4l.org/ecDZE

Comment: @Sammich I have not succeeded in creating a simple way to reproduce the problem either.

Comment: startup errors also enabled? http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors . See also [php](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) tag info

Comment: Do you define `OtherClass` before or after `Foo`?

Comment: Check your logs. If you can't gin up a repro, error message, logs, or any concrete info about the issue no one's going to be able to help, no matter how hard they want to.

Comment: @Bamar I thought that might be the winner, but I just tested and the order they are defined doesn't seem to mater. I'll do more tests for that, though.

Comment: @Sammich, I hear you, and I'm working on it. My question in this case was more whether anyone was aware of a change to the language that might be affecting me. Though the fact that php is bailing without leaving any trace makes me wonder if I might have stumbled on a bug in php itself.

Comment: `display_startup_errors = On` had no effect.

Comment: It does sound like possible PHP bug to me. The fact that it worked in 7.2 and depends on the file organization supports that.

Comment: Please show the other cass and the includes. Hard facts are better than blackbox guessing.

Comment: If you can come up with a way to reproduce it, you might want to submit it as a PHP bug report.

Comment: I'm working on it; I guess I know what I'll be doing this weekend.

Comment: Properly declared and included it works fine on my PHP 7.3.1, 7.3.0, 7.2.2, no bug to confirm

Comment: Honestly, I suggest setting up [`XDebug` and running the profiler](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler), then running your script with profiling enabled. Once the script fails, check out the profiler results and see what's at the end of the trace that can be causing the issue/early termination. Other than that, what environment is php 7.3 installed on and what architecture are you using, x64 NTS/TS? etc. I have a suspicion, that it might by on something like CentOS 6.9 with a remi RPM, that might not be 100% stable, or similar

Comment: Also are you running it in the CLI or through a proxy like php-fpm or Apache module?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can do it like this:

```
function bar($param = null) {
    if ($param === null) {
        $param = OtherClass::MY_CONSTANT;
    }
    logger(__METHOD__);
    logger(OtherClass::MY_CONSTANT);
    logger($param);
    logger('ready to do stuff');

    // does stuff
}
```

This assumes that `null` is not a valid value for the parameter; replace that with some other invalid value if it is. If the parameter can legitimately be anything, this workaround won't work.

Comment: This does not make any difference. If `OtherClass::MY_CONSTANT` is declared and accessible, it can be used as default parameter or within the code body as well - otherwise not.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone It *should* work the way he originally wrote it. It seems like a PHP bug, hence the workaround.

Comment: This workaround does in fact work. As I said above, I can use the constant anywhere except as a default parameter value.